# Why aren't these two nodes black in a red-black tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, tree, red-black-tree

As I understood it, in a red-black tree, when I insert a new node, and when I encounter a black node with 2 red children on my way down, I need to flip the colors, i.e. make the parent red and its 2 children black (except from the root).

I saw this picture on Wikipedia:

[image]

Why aren't 8 and 17 black?

I also check in a [applet](http://mainline.brynmawr.edu/Courses/cs206/spring2004/WorkshopApplets/Chap09/RBTree/RBTree.html) taken from "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" by Lafore; same thing there, these nodes become black.

Is there multiple of versions of this red-black tree?

Comment: Could it be that you are answering your own question when you say, _"except from the root"_? 8 and 17 *are* the root's child nodes.

Comment: I meant that when the root is flipping keep it black

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite possible to make those nodes black.  There might be several different ways to color the nodes of a tree such that the resulting tree obeys the structural constraints of a red/black tree.  For example, any perfect binary tree could be colored such that all nodes are black, or could have the rows alternate between red and black, etc.

The specific rules for recoloring and rotating nodes in a red/black tree are not the only possible rules.  They're just ones that happen to work correctly and efficiently.  We could in principle change them so that the tree is colored and rotated in a different way, which might give rise to different colors or shapes for trees with the same nodes.

Hope this helps!